# Why does my code run on one program but not the other?

Tags: python, console, sublimerepl

I am writing a simple number guessing game and I cannot get my code to execute in SublimeREPL or my console. The only way I can get it to execute in Team Treehouse's Workspaces program, and it works exactly the way it is supposed to. But in both my console and SublimeREPL it says there are multiple indentation errors. What gives?? I know python is finnicky about its indentation so I made sure to change my sublime settings so that each tab is four spaces but it still does not run - throws about ten indentation errors, but as far as I can tell everything is indented exactly how it is supposed to be. I have tried multiple searches with no results and I am at my wits end not being able to get such a simple program to run! I mean why would code work in one environment but not in another? I'm copying and pasting the code so it's not different...

Here is the code:

```
import random

#safely make an int
#limit guesses
#too high, too low, messages
#play again

def game():
    #generate number
    secret_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    guesses = []

    while len(guesses) < 5:
        try:
            #get num guess from user
            guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not a valid number, try again.")

        else:
            #compare guess to secret number
            if guess == secret_number:
                #print hit/miss
                print("You got it! My number was {}".format(secret_number))
                break
            else:
                print("That's not it! Guess again!")
            guesses.append(guess)

game()
```

Note this code works perfectly on Team Treehouse.
Here is the error I receive in SublimeREPL and my terminal:

```
    Guess a number between one and ten: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    if guess == secret_num:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("You got it!")
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    break
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>   File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("That's not it!") 
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> >>>
```

I would seriously prefer to use tools other than Workspaces so I can have my own code on my machine, but I don't know if this code will even actually work or if I am just wasting my time learning junk...

Comment: That probably means you're mixing spaces and tabs to indent, which you shouldn't do. Some IDEs handle this well, some don't.

Comment: I know pycharm can automagically fix a lot of this for you.  I think many other editors will as well.

Comment: In the IDE that it works in, see if it has an option to convert all indentation to spaces or tabs. Then, make sure you're consistent in what you're indenting with.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Am I supposed to indent with tabs or spaces? Because I have people telling me both.

Comment: I have completely deleted the indentation in the program and re added it as both tabs and as spaces and neither time did it work. Rather, they work on Team Treehouse but not in my console or in SublimeREPL.

Comment: The problem is that if you put code into the REPL like this, then blank lines will signal the end of a block, and then the rest of the lines have inappropriate indentation to stand by themselves. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score -1):

Open your code in sublime, click on `Spaces:4/Tab Size: 4` in bottom right  hand corner. Click on `Indent using spaces` in the dropdown. It should fix your mixed tab and spaces issue.

Comment: I have done that and deleted all indentation and re entered it as tabs, and then deleted and and entered them as spaces as well and neither worked..

Answer (score -1):

According to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), the Python Style Guide, indentation should consist of 4 spaces. Tabs should not be used, unless you are working on a large legacy Python 2 project that already uses tabs.

To change your indentation to all spaces, select **`View → Indentation`** and make sure **`Indent Using Spaces`** and **`Tab Width: 4`** are selected. Then, select **`View → Indentation → Convert Indentation to Spaces`** to change any extant tabs to spaces. Review your entire file to ensure that the indentation is correct, then save and run it.

Comment: Just did that and got the exact same error. The funny thing is when I use this code in workspaces, (a partial ide from team treehouse) it executes perfectly and works as expected. But I don't want to write software to be used in workspaces. I want it to work in other programs and other machines otherwise what I am learning is useless.....

Comment: @LouieWilliford please edit your question to include the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks you are getting, so we can see exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: Edited for you! Thank you so much for your help this has seriously been keeping me stuck for two days!!

Comment: @LouieWilliford I don't know what's going on. I just copied and pasted the code from your question into a new Python file in Sublime, saved it, opened an IPython REPL, selected **`Tools → SublimeREPL → Eval in REPL → File`**, switched to the REPL, and ran the game, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This is seriously discouraging. What is the point of learning a language if I cant even write it on my own machine....

Comment: Thank you for your time either way, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @LouieWilliford here's what I would do: Open a new Python file in Sublime, and rewrite your program from scratch, making sure that you're using 4 spaces for indentation. It'll take a little while, but it should work.